# Xcode gives a generic error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) when trying to parsing JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, macos, parsing

When parsing JSON I get a strange Xcode error.
Usually this code works fine.  (I get perfect results for about a dozen folders, only one gives the (below) error.)
(Before this, I had a coulpe of JSON decoding errors then marked the swift object elements as optional then all worked .. until).

Here is the code fragment that I use:

```
    getContentWithToken(path, completion: { (result) in
        guard let json = result as? Data else {
            print("cannot get data from response")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showAlert("Error", "cannot get data from response", ["OK"], completion: { (response) in
                })
            }
            return
        }
        do {
            let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(DItem.self, from: json)
            print ("items: \(items)")
...
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
...
        }
    }
```

Xcode highlights the first line under *do* (*let items = try*...) and present the error "Thread 11: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7000065e3ff8)".

*AFAIK*, with *do..catch* statements, if any part in *do* fails, then *catch* is used as no xcode error arises.  For example, a few times the *do*{} failed and the *catch*{} executed and displayed where the JSON had failed...

NOTE: To avoid force-unwrap-optional errors the code uses guard and *do..catch*.  This approach also gives exact JSON-parsing errors if any.  Also my DItem object conforms to Codable.  I am trying to parse JSON data using a given API, to get a list of files/sub-folders, in a range of folders.

**Is there a way I can avoid this Xcode error?**

Comment: I assume the issue is in the JSON or in your Codable object, if you can, post that code and we'll see.

Comment: @Adis Because it's complex and long, I tried to add to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/F1uy6YDR

Comment: Is it always reproducible for the same test data or is it random? I assume this is some asynchronous call, can you test with local data in an non asynchronous manner?